# How to prevent double click on a JointJs Rectangle?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas, jointjs

I am developing a simple graphic tool using JointJs. while double clicking on a element will executes a function. How to prevent double click event for rectangle.

***Already tried the below snippet but I need to drag the rectangle***

```
rect: { 
          style: { 'pointer-events': 'none' }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

paper.on('cell:pointerdblclick', function(cellView) {

```
    if (cellView.model.get('type') === 'basic.Rect') {
        return;
    }

    console.log("not a rect")
});
```

or, using css:

```
.joint-element[data-type="basic.Rect"] {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```